# How to render index.html file that is in wwwroot folder using controller or view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, static-files, wwwroot

I have an `index.html` file stored in the `wwwroot` folder but I want to access it from view or controller outside any way by using redirect from controller or view.

Comment: Follow any tutorial. You probably don't know whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

as you decribed,the index.html is a staticfile that could  be accessed with uri like: https://localhost:5001/index.html,
controller is not necessary.
If you want to render it in your view,you could try `<iframe src=~/index.html></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the line `app.UseDefaultFiles();` in `startup.cs` in Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();     // this line of code.                                  
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```